# mail that i put in trash return in my inbox until i remove totally from trash

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

i use google apps for automatize some script in my landing page and put mail detail in google sheet after the script to include info in sheet i  delete mail , the next time that script gone the previous mail seems to be in inbox folder but when i check on gmail account the mail is in trash folder ,

```
function parseEmailMessages(start) {

  start = start || 0;
  var threads = [];


  GmailApp.refreshThreads(threads)
  threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,20);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
     // subject = message.getSubject(),
     subject = message.getSubject(),
      content = message.getPlainBody();
    if(threads[i].isUnread()){
      if(subject=="Promozioni Millemutui - Calcola Rata" || subject=="Richiesta contatto da promozione millemutui - Gran Mutuo liquidità" || subject=="Richiesta contatto da promozione millemutui - Mutuo 100%" || subject=="Richiesta contatto da promozione millemutui - Rifinanziamento debiti più liquidità" ){
        if (content) {

          var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
          tmp = content.match(/Cognome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
          var cognome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Nessun cognome  ';

          tmp = content.match(/Nome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
          var nome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Nessun nome ';

          tmp = content.match(/EMail:\s*([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
          var EMail = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No email';


          tmp = content.match(/Numero di telefono:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
          var Numeroditelefono = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Nessun numero ';


          //tmp = content.match(/Messaggio:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
          tmp = content.match(/Messaggio:\s*([\s\S]+)/);
          var Messaggio = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Nessun messaggio ';

          sheet.appendRow([date,"",cognome,nome,Numeroditelefono,Messaggio,"",EMail,"Google","AUTO",subject]);

        } 

      threads[i].markRead()
      //threads[i].moveToArchive()

      threads[i].moveToTrash()

      threads[i].refresh()

    }
   }

  } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `threads[i].moveToArchive()` commented? Try uncommenting it, does it resolve your issue?

Comment: hi ross , it's only a test to verify if i put into the archive works , but i have the same result , the next time script run i find the thread into inbox , despite if i check trash in webmail of gmail and the message is in trash

Comment: Hi Francesco, I'm trying to replicate your issue, but your code works with no problem for me, I removed the subject check and the appending section, since your issue seems to be with just the email.When you say that the email seems to still be there, do you mean on a separate execution of the code? Also, when you check `if(content)` are you trying to see if it's empty? Lastly, is the code populating your sheet as expected?